# Is there a OpenFDA API Basics for medical devices?

Tags: openfda, uses-of-open-data

Reading the documentation of [OpenFDA fields](https://open.fda.gov/drug/event/reference/#openfda-fields), we are linked to the [API Basics reference guide](https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/#openfda-fields). Every time that I try to find information about API fields (including other questions on this site) I end up landing on that same page.

Unfortunately (to me) the NDC sections explains some dataset fields that are used to annotate records in openFDA regarding drugs. I can't find a similar thing for devices.

Is there a API or field list for medical devices related information?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the endpoint. For instance,
https://open.fda.gov/device/classification/reference/#openfda

That's where you can find reference info for the openfda fields for the `Device/Classification` endpoint.